# How to generate body pose keypoints like dresscode using openpose

Tags: python, keypoint, openpose, dresscode

As per the description, Keypoints are described in dresscode as:
For all image pairs of the dataset, we stored the joint coordinates of human poses. In particular, we used OpenPose [1] to extract 18 keypoints for each human body.

For each image, we provided a json file containing a dictionary with the keypoints key. The value of this key is a list of 18 elements, representing the joints of the human body. Each element is a list of 4 values, where the first two indicate the coordinates on the x and y axis respectively.

What I did is for vton where we have 74 points in pose_2d. Not sure how to do it for dresscode.

```
./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --image_dir examples/media/ --write_json output_jsons/ --disable_blending
```